# Laravel transfer files using ftp

Tags: php, laravel, ftp, file-transfer

I have a file on one server which is inside storage folder. I would like to transfer this file to an external server via ftp.

I've tried using https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Flysystem

But the issue is that it only allows me to update and read the file. So if lets say test.txt does not exist, it will return Undefined offset: 8 which I traced down to being file not found

This is the function that is breaking:

```
$fileName = "test2.txt"
$filePath = "path/to/file/to/transfer/test.txt" 
$this->flysystem->connection('ftp')->write($fileName,$filePath);
```

File test2.txt does not exist on server 2

This functions allow me to update the file

```
$this->flysystem->connection('ftp')->put('test.txt','test');
```

File test.txt exist on server 2

Also I'm trying to transfer .zip files but testing on txt

Thanks

Comment: check the file and folder permission

Comment: have you tried using the 'copy' method instead of 'put'

Comment: @nrivero, yes I've tried the copy,write & put methods.

Comment: @SushilShukla, I've checked permissions and they seem to be ok. After all, it allows me to update the file.

Comment: You say test2.txt and then test.txt for your update?

Comment: @Mark Davidson no, for update I did   test.txt , 'File contents'

Comment: @Mark Davidson If I would use $this->flysystem->connection('ftp')->update('test2.txt','test.txt'), it would take the second argument in the string and use it as file contents

Comment: can you check with other ext file there ?

Comment: if that is not  working than talk to your server support....

Comment: Nope, its not unfortinantley, thanks

Comment: are you getting an FTP error message? like a 553?

Comment: No, no error message. But the strange thing is I can create a directory, so maybe theres something wrong with the code? I'm using absolute path to get the file on server 1, would that may cause any problems?

Comment: they should be relative to the adapter root directory

Comment: Ok, I was able to retreive file contents from file to be trasnfered, but I'm still not ablet o create new files for some reason, even if it would be an empy file

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
$stream = fopen("path/to/file/to/transfer/test.txt" , 'r+');
$this->flysystem->connection('ftp')->writeStream('uploads/test.txt', $stream);
fclose($stream);
```

Comment: Tried it, still getting  Undefined offset: 8